# App Crashes When Navigaiton Drawer Item is Pressed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, crash

**UPDATE : PROBLEM IS SOLVED**

[image]

According to this image, I am trying to open fragment according to each drawer item. Currently I've made fragment only for 'Easy' which contain **a ListView** but my app **CRASHES** everytime I press it. I've Android Nougat (v7.0) running on my phone.

Here is my code ...

**Fragment Layout (fragment_easy.xml) :**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="afm.pymonk.EasyFragment"
    android:id="@+id/easyFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/easyList"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment JAVA Code inside onCreateView in EasyFragment.java :**

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_easy, container, false);

String easyListContents[] = {"Introduction", "Hello World", "Operators", "Data Types",
            "Simple Arithmetic Operations", "Take input from user"};

ListView easyList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.easyList);
ArrayAdapter<String> easyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EasyFragment.this.getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, easyListContents);
easyList.setAdapter(easyAdapter);

easyList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        return;
    }
});

return view;
```

**Code to open fragemnt inside onNavigationItemSelected in main activity (Home.java) :**

```
int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.icon_easy) {
    EasyFragment easyFragment = new EasyFragment();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainBase, easyFragment, easyFragment.getTag()).commit();
}
```

**Device Error Log :**

[image]

Comment: Can you share your logcat error log ?

Comment: @MoraS. how do I do that ? Tell me, i'll share it surely.

Comment: In AndroidStudio, there's a bottom panel "Android Monitor" should give you access to device logs https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-monitor.html

Comment: Thanks @MoraS. , now I've included it in my Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return `view` not `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_easy, container, false);` in your fragment in onCreateView  method.

Edited :

Implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in MainActvity

Ex:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnFragmentInteractionListener {

// Implement the methods here
}
```

Comment: but i guess , even without this change the app should not crash but should show just a static layout doing nothing

Comment: It still crashes.

Comment: check out the error log ! I don't even understand the log thing ! Maybe you can find out ...

Comment: @Shivam Do you have **OnFragmentInteractionListener** interface in your fragment..?

Comment: No I don't have it @MuthukrishnanRajendran

Comment: In you MainActvity implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: in EasyFragment onActtach you might have used that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151522/discussion-between-muthukrishnan-rajendran-and-shivam).

Answer (score 1):

Your `easyFragment.getTag()` call will return `null` because there was no `setTag` call, so just use some `String` tag to bind it with your fragment instead of`null`

```
 manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainBase, easyFragment, "easyFrag").commit();
//                                                                 ^^^^^^
```

Update :

You are using interface listener callbacks in fragment but there is no implementation in your activity so make sure to do

```
class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener {
  //                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 // override methods of OnFragmentInteractionListener and provide their implementation
}
```